# Serilog MinimumLevel.Override

Tags: serilog

My question is how granular do I need to be with Serilog MinimumLevel.Override when it comes to the source?

For example I want to have all messages from Microsoft be logged at the Warning Level.

Will the source "Microsoft" be adequate?

```
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

Or do I need to do something like this:

```
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

will cause all events from `Microsoft`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`, etc., to be logged at the `Warning` level and above. It's not necessary to list every child namespace.